# Angular MatSelect Not Retaining Selected Value in Reactive Form on Submit

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm working with an Angular reactive form that includes a **`<mat-select>`** for city selection. While the dropdown correctly displays and allows for city selection, I'm encountering an issue when attempting to submit the form: the selected value for **`ciudad_id`** doesn't seem to be retained or properly captured in the form object upon submission.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="form-group has-default">
  <mat-form-field class="input-group full-width">
    <mat-icon matPrefix>location_city</mat-icon> 
    <mat-select matInput placeholder="Ciudad" formControlName="ciudad_id">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let ciudad of ciudades" [value]="ciudad.id">{{ciudad.nombre}}</mat-option>
    </mat-select>
    <mat-error *ngIf="ciudad_id?.invalid && ciudad_id?.dirty">
      The city is required.
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</div>
```

In the component, I initialize the form and load cities correctly. However, upon form submission, the value of **`ciudad_id`** seems to be either not present or not correctly captured:

**TS:**

```
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit{
  form!: FormGroup;
  ciudades = [];

  constructor(private _form_builder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeForm();
    this.loadCities();
  }

  private initializeForm() {
    this.form = this._form_builder.group({
      ciudad_id: ['', Validators.required],
      // other form controls...
    });
  }

  loadCities() {
    // Load cities from a service and assign to `ciudades`
  }

  onSubmit() {
    console.log("Form submitted:", this.form.value);
    // Here, `ciudad_id` does not retain the selected value
  }
}
```

I've tried subscribing to value changes with **`valueChanges`** and confirmed the value correctly changes when selecting a different option. I've also ensured the form is correctly bound and there are no typographical or configuration errors. Yet, the issue persists.

Has anyone faced a similar issue or has any idea why the selected value for **`ciudad_id`** is not retained upon form submission?

Comment: Are you disabling the form control?  If so `form.value` won't include disabled fields.  Log out `this.form.getRawValue()` and see if your value is included.

Comment: There might be an issue with the ids you are using as value in select options or make sure you have added `[formGroup]="form"` in your form tag as an attribute. If you share stackblitz or repo then we can check more in it.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try adding `id` and `name` and check if the issue still occours, if not please replicate the issue on a stackblitz and update the question!

```
....
 <mat-form-field class="input-group full-width">
    <mat-icon matPrefix>location_city</mat-icon> 
    <mat-select matInput placeholder="Ciudad" formControlName="ciudad_id"
          id="ciudad_id" name="ciudad_id"> <!-- changed here -->
      <mat-option *ngFor="let ciudad of ciudades" [value]="ciudad.id">{{ciudad.nombre}}</mat-option>
          ....
```

Answer (score 0):

What could be tried is debugging the `ciudad.id` value.

```
<mat-option *ngFor="let ciudad of ciudades" [value]="ciudad.id">The id: {{ciudad.id}}</mat-option>
```

Also what could be tried is display somewhere in the page the current value:

```
<div>
    {{ form.value | json }}
</div>
```

Another thing is there is nowhere a `formGroup`. Isn't it missing?

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    ...
</div>
```